# UITextView does not update during loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uitextview

so I have tried 2 different ways to display the timer count down on the screen.

the code will print to the console but not to the UITextView (in both loop cases) in the repeat the UITextView ends with a 0 and that is the only thing it displays other than original txt "time count".... in the case where the commented loop is implemented the UITextView only displays the 1 (end of count down)... why is it printing to the console though these commands are in the same brackets as UITextView and they repeat

the image is after running code and clicking Soft (this is spin off of app brewery egg timer)

---

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  EggTimer
//
//  Created by Angela Yu on 08/07/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 The App Brewery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

let softTime = 5
let medTime = 7
let hardTime = 12

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timerTextView: UITextView!
    
    @IBAction func eggHardnessButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle
        func timeCountDownSoft() {
            var time = 3
            repeat {
                time = time - 1 //repeats
                timerTextView.selectAll("") // does not repeat
                timerTextView.insertText("") // does not repeat
                let timeWord = String(time) // repeats
                timerTextView.insertText(timeWord)//does not repeat
                print(time) //repeats
                sleep(1) //repeats
                
            } while time >= 1
            
            /*for timer in stride(from: 2, to: 0 , by: -1){
             let time = String(timer)
             timerTextView.selectAll("")
             timerTextView.insertText("")
             timerTextView.insertText(time)
             print(time)
             sleep(1)
             }*/
        }
        func timeCountDownMed() {
            for timer in stride(from: 420, to: 0 , by: -1) {
                print(timer)
                sleep(1)
            }
        }
        func timeCountDownHard() {
            for timer in stride(from: 720, to: 0 , by: -1) {
                print(timer)
                sleep(1)
            }
        }
        if hardness == "Soft" {
            print(softTime) // does not repeat
            timeCountDownSoft() // does not repeat
            
            
        } else if hardness == "Medium" {
            print(medTime)
            timeCountDownMed()
        } else {
            print(hardTime)
            timeCountDownHard()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep` stops the current thread. It wouldn't be able to update the UI the way you've written it. If you'd like to use a timer you can just use [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer).

Comment: I recommend you don't use sleep... did the course really do that? I took it a while ago but forget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never (well, ***almost never***) want to use `sleep()`.

The reason your text is not updating is because you are running closed-loops that never allow UIKit to update the view.

What you want to do instead is to use a repeating `Timer` with a `one-second` interval. Each time the timer fires, decrement your counter and update the UI. When the counter reaches Zero, stop the timer.

Here's a simple example:

```
import UIKit

let softTime = 5
let medTime = 7
let hardTime = 12

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timerTextView: UITextView!
    
    var theTimer: Timer?
    
    @IBAction func eggHardnessButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle
        var numSeconds = 0

        // set number of seconds based on button title
        switch hardness {
        case "Soft":
            numSeconds = softTime * 60
        case "Medium":
            numSeconds = medTime * 60
        case "Hard":
            numSeconds = hardTime * 60
        default:
            // some other button called this func, so just return
            return()
        }

        // stop current timer if it's running
        if let t = theTimer {
            if t.isValid {
                t.invalidate()
            }
        }
        
        // update text field with selected time
        let timeWord = String(numSeconds)
        self.timerTextView.text = timeWord

        // start a timer with 1-second interval
        theTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            numSeconds -= 1
            let timeWord = String(numSeconds)
            self.timerTextView.text = timeWord
            // if we've reached Zero seconds remaining
            if numSeconds == 0 {
                // stop the timer
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does the timer execute it's block on the main thread?  Just wondering about the UI update.

Comment: @flanker - from Apple's docs: `Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.` ... so, in this example, if the `eggHardnessButton()` func is called on the main thread - such as in response to `.touchUpInside` - then the timer is running on the main thread.

Comment: I read that @DonMag, but wasn't sure if `run loop in the default mode` meant on the main thread.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- When your app changes the UI, those changes do not actually get
  rendered to the screen until your code returns and visits the app's
  event loop. Thus, with your repeat loop, nothing will show up on in
  the UI until the loop completes
- Do not use sleep() on the main thread. That blocks everything, and
  your app comes to a screeching halt.
- If you want to update the UI once a second, set up a repeating timer
  that fires once a second and do your UI updates in the timer code.